# Кодировка для соеденения с бд

Tags: mysql, база-данных, кодировка

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in.
Нужно задать кодировку для бд. Если данные формы будут на анг. языке то на базе они выглядят без ошибок, но если данные формы будут на русском языке то на базе поивляются какие то ромбы, помогите пж сроки горят!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: к ошибке ваш вопрос не имеет отношения. а так - проверьте кодировку скрипта и базы

Answer (score -1):

1. содержание ошибки говорит, что ты не верно прописываешь базу данных
2. кодировка должна быть ютф8, как в базе данных, так и самого файла скрипта, так и хтмл, так же в хтаске указать её не помешает

Comment: хтаске? А что это?

Comment: Я на всё установил кодировку utf8 но в базе данных mysql показывает какие то абра кадабры

Comment: чтаск=htaccess. Возможно кодировка отображения базы данных указана не корректно (встречается иногда на англоязычных хостах).